# How can I display the name of the current worksheet in a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to be able to display the name of the current worksheet in a cell on that worksheet.

How can I do that without resorting to VBA scripts?

If it matters, the particular flavor of Excel I'm working with is 2007, but I would prefer something as version-agnostic as possible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
=RIGHT(CELL("filename",A1),LEN(CELL("filename",A1))-FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1),1))
```

The workbook needs to be saved before this function works.

The key to the function is `=CELL("filename",A1)`, which returns a handy string that includes the file path, the file name, and the worksheet name: `C:\Users\john.smith\Desktop\[Test.xlsx]Sheet1`

See:

- http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/formulae/cell_function.html
- http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/399701-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-sheet-in-a-cell.html

Comment: The cell reference `A1` is optional, no?

Comment: This works for me: `=RIGHT(CELL("filename"),LEN(CELL("filename"))-SEARCH("]",CELL("filename")))`

Comment: You can omit the cell reference and it does not matter if you only have one Cell() function in the file. However, if you use the cell function to show the sheet name on each sheet, you need the A1 reference, otherwise each sheet will show the same value. Which value is shown depends on which formula was last recalculated. So, put the formula in Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, without a reference to A1. When you recalculate Sheet3, it will show "Sheet3". Go to Sheet1 and it will also show "Sheet3". -- Probably not what you want. But with a cell reference, the formula will work as expected.

Comment: Slightly shorter.....`=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,32)`